# How to fix "moov atom not found" when extracting an image from partial video mp4 file?

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg, video-processing, ffmpegthumbnailer

I think the problem is relatively common, but I can't find any good solution to my problem.
Well, I need to create a preview of the video while it uploads. It can be a very big video, so I decided to use only the first 10 Mb of video to make image extraction with **ffmpeg**.

The command-line looks like this

`ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -i "src.mp4" -frames:v 1 -q:v 2 "preview.jpg"`

It works fine for lots of video files, but for mp4 it always failed with the error message "Moov atom not found". I guess the mp4 format is not streamable and the cut file looks like a broken video for the FFmpeg.

But there should be a solution to this. Could you help me?

Comment: moov is at either of 2 spots  ( Beginning,  End )   if your reqmts incl MOOV and its at the end, your gonna need a full pass in order to ( Get Moov,   repostion Moov from END to Beginning )

Comment: @RobertRowntree Unfortunately I haven't source mp4 file to make any operations with it (including MOOV location change). I only have first 10 Mb and what I need is extract the preview from them somehow..

Comment: If you only have the first 10mb, and the moov is at the end, then you can’t extract the image. It just not possible.

Comment: Extract the required frame before uploading to the server. It's not obvious if the input video is from a user selected file or something like a livestream. In any case the simplest way is decode/play video, then get required image, then upload to server. MP4 a/v contauiner needs moov atom but the video codec (picture) itself (H264) does not need such atom so maybe try to get the h.264 before putting into MP4 container.

Comment: @vc.one Thanks for the advice. Unfortunately I can't have any control on the uploaded file, but since the file uploading from the app I am creating, I guess the best solution will be to extract preview on the client/app side.

Comment: Why don't you have control over uploads? Are you not the creator of the "upload" button? Can your button's function not first get an image (through decoding the selected file) and then send bytes to server? What is your input (user file or live stream)?

Comment: @VC.One I am the creator of the app. People will use it to upload BIG or small video files. The file format is different, mp4/mov is not so rare. Initially, I had an idea to use the server for generation previews. But it looks like it will be much better to generate thumbnails on the client side. For the iOS/Android it should not be a big problem. Still the question about web application (is it possible to make a thumbnail from 8Gb video file in a browser)